# Doctrine send an entity to DQL's NEW constructor

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dto

I have a Blog application in Symfony2 with Doctrine, made of three entities

- Post
- Comment
- User
- one Post can have many Comments
- one User can have many comments

this application has an json API call  "/me/comments"

I would like it to return

```
[
    {
       'text': 'great post',
       ... 10 other field a comment can have ...
       'post': { 'id': 3}
    },
    {
       'text': 'i dont like it',
       ... 10 other field a comment can have ...
       'post': {'id': 4}
    },

]
```

The normal doctrine function returns me all the relation (User, Post) in the json, which I don't want as Post can contains huge text, so i'm only interested in the Id

I've tried many solutions and I've found that one

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax

so now my DQL query looks like that

`SELECT NEW CommentDTO(c) FROM Comment as c WHERE c.author = :user`

the constructor of CommentDTO looks like that

```
__construct(Comment c) {
   $this->text = c.getText();
   $this->post = [ 'id' => c.getPost().getId() ];
}
```

when I execute it I got

```
{
   "code":500,
   "message":"Argument 1 passed to MVMS\\ApiBundle\\Entity\\CommentDTO::__construct() must be an instance of MVMS\\ApiBundle\\En
tity\\Comment, integer given"

}
```

of course I could give the parameter one by one but Comment has a dozen of fields and sending them one by one seems highly hackish.

Is there a way to send the object directly ?

Comment: If you want only `text` and `post_id` why do you need to fetch whole comment? And if you want fetch whole comment why do you not want to fetch it standard way?

Comment: From your link: "Note that you can only pass scalar expressions to the constructor."  So you might consider using DBAL and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Cerad in the comments, there is no current way to achieve this, according to the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax), which is still relevant in 2017:

> Note that you can only pass scalar expressions to the constructor.

I could not find a related feature request in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues), so it will likely not be implemented in the foreseeable future.