# Doctrine inheritance with only one table possible?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Doctrine model I want to have a `BasePerson` class which has all the database persisted fields.

```
 * @ORM\Entity()
class BasePerson 
{
   $street;
   $number;
   ...
}
```

I also want to have a `Person` class extending from the base person class which has additionally a entitylistener attached. The listener triggers an API call and filling my "Person" Entity with the location data.

```
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"..."})
class Person extends BasePerson 
{
  $location;
}
```

For all base operations without needing API calls I want to use the `BasePerson` class, and for all API related operation I will use the `Person` class; but in every case I have at least the information coming from the database.

The problem now is, whenever I add the  `@ORM\Entity()` annotation to both entities, Doctrine thinks this should be two tables. I don't want two tables. If I left the entity annotation on one of both entities, doctrine gives me an error, that this entity is unmanaged ...

How can I have it all in one table? I read about single table inheritance but for this, doctrine will manage this with an discriminator column ... but that's not the use case for my intend ...

Answer (score 1):

To have a clean architecture, you should use the same entity and two [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s. One for the API and add it the attribute "location" and the other for other views of project.

Doctrine (version >= 2.4) can directly return a DTO from a query using "[NEW](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax)" operator, an example:

```
<?php

$this
    ->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('NEW Acme\DTO\CategoryListView(category.id, category.title)')
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Category', 'category');
```

Comment: Would using a DTO layer - based on the same entity - prevent calling the EntityListener? I don't think so ... or how would you manage this with DTO's?

Comment: Doctrine can directly return a DTO from a query, an example: `$this
    ->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('NEW Acme\DTO\CategoryListView(category.id, category.title)')
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Category', 'category');`

Comment: I cant imagine how to unite the DTO idea with my application ... i am using sonata admin which wants an entity to work with. I cant inject a DTO to my admin services to work with.

Comment: Assume the BasePerson holds an Adress-Entity  ... how can i fetch this  via SELECT NEW ... query? When i join the related entity ("SELECT NEW PersonDTO(p.street, p.number, a) FROM Person JOIN p.address a") i get an error in my PersonDTO constructor which receives an "int" instead of an object of type "Address"

Comment: Ok, i found this on the web https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004687/doctrine-send-an-entity-to-dqls-new-constructor ... here it seems its only possible to pass scalar values to constructor ... and thats the reason why DTO approach fits not to my needs ...

Comment: In this case, instead of passing all the entity as a parameter you can just pass specific fields and in the constructor you can create another DTO to the related entity from passed fields

Answer (score 0):

You can just have some method related to API in your Person class and use them only when needed. I don't see why this would be such an issue.

I don't think you should be using the BasePerson class directly.
I assume Doctrine would not allow the behaviour you're trying to have.

Comment: The problem i have is, that whenever i load the class with the entitylistener, my api call is prerformed. But there are many cases i dont want to invoke an api call. Lets say i only want the street of my person. In this case there is no need for getting the actual location ... so my idea was to use two classes ... one for simple information from local database, and the extended version whenever i need api information